# GET/POST в React

Tags: reactjs, post, get, axios, fetch

Сервер моего проекта читает api стороннего сайта, обрабатывает и записывает в базу данных. Весь бэкэнд написан на Java.

Со стороны клиента хочу отрисовывать некоторые графики по полученным с сервера данным в формате JSON.

Насколько я понимаю, сначала нам необходимо из UI методом POST отправить данные какой-нибудь формы, например, с датами

```
http://localhost:3001/chart/?fromDate=2018-12-20&toDate=2018-12-21
```

Затем, сервер обрабатывает данные и отправляет мне JSON файл, который мне необходимо считать методом GET.

Вопрос: как правильно реализовать обмен данными с точки зрения жизненных циклов компонента и какие инструменты на ваш взгяд лучше всего для этого использовать (fetch/axios...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Делаем `GET` запрос на сервер в `componentDidMount`, в ответ приходит `json`, мы его приводим к необходимой структуре и скармливаем в компенент с графиками

Все реализуется в одном цилке: мы спросили - нам ответили

`Fetch` / `axios` / `graphql`.. для такой задачи хватит и `fetch`, но можно использовать любой